# How To Deal with Time only and Date only in Sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

According to msdn the general standart for datetime is

```
select convert(datetime,'19781222',112)       //YYYYMMDD
```

So if i want to insert into datetime this value i can do it by

```
update [Readings] set  [StartDate] = '19781222'
```

But what about time ?  how do i add the Time to the YYYYMMDD ?

**Question 2 :**  how do i update only the time in DateTime ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st part:

```
 update [Readings] 
 set  [StartDate] = '19781222 10:23:56'   -- YYYYMMDD
```

2nd:

```
update [Readings] 
set  [StartDate] = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [StartDate]), 0) + '12:34:37'
```

[The ultimate guide to the datetime datatypes](http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Only time:
    select convert(datetime,'18:22:39',108) //hh:mm:ss